# Como contar caracteres especifico

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que conte quantas vogais existem na palavra, eu consegui fazer, agora estava tentando fazer só contar uma vogal na palavra, por exemplo Rafael, o a aparece 2 vezes, eu quero que conte apenas uma vez, poderiam me ajudar ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nome[100];
  char vogais[11]={"AEIOUaeiou"};
  int cont=0;
  scanf("%s",nome);
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(nome);i++)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<strlen(vogais);j++)
     {
         if(nome[i]==vogais[j])
         {
            cont++;
         }
     }
 }
  printf("%d\n",cont);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você quer saber se uma vogal específica está presente ou quantas vogais específicas existem?

Comment: Quantas vogais tem na palavra, sem contar as  vogais repetidas na palavra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nome[100];
    char vogais[11] = {"AEIOUaeiou"};
    int cont = 0;
    int existeVogais[10];
    scanf("%s",nome);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(nome); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(vogais); j++) {
            if(nome[i] == vogais[j]) {
                existeVogais[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (existeVogais[i] == 1){
            printf("Existe a vogal %c\n",vogais[i]);
            cont += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nPortanto tempos %d vogais na palavra\n",cont);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode Ser Feito dessa maneira também, como em **C** não tem booleano, a gente cria um usando variáveis inteiras:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nome[100];
  char vogais[5]={"AEIOU"};
  int cont=0, a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;
  scanf("%s",nome);
  strupr(nome);
  for(int i=0; i < strlen(nome); i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j < 5; j++)
    {
       if(nome[i]==vogais[j])
       {
           if(nome[i] == 'A') a++;
           else if(nome[i] == 'E') e++;
           else if(nome[i] == 'I') i++;
           else if(nome[i] == 'O') o++;
           else if(nome[i] == 'U') u++;
       }
    }

  }

if(a > 0) cont++;
if(e > 0) cont++;
if(i > 0) cont++;
if(o > 0) cont++;
if(u > 0) cont++;

printf("%d\n",cont);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma não é muito prática pois temos que testar as 10 opções (você fez apenas com as letras maiúsculas). Sem falar na quantidade de teste que tem que ser feito a cada interação, aumentando muito o tempo de processamento. Não que isso vá deixar o programa lento (é um programa muito simples), mas o ideal é programar sempre prestando atenção em performasse.

Comment: Eu subir a cadeia de caracteres todas pra maiúsculas utilizando a função **"strupr"** então isto não será um problema, já a performasse realmente ele nao seja tão bom mas como você mesmo disse és um programa simples.

Comment: Phelipe, você poderia me explicar, essa parte existeVogais[j] = 1;